# Exception handling in Application_Error, what is sender.Context.Request?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have Exception-handling code in my Application_Error. I got the code from stackoverflow, its working.

```
protected void Application_Error(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string currentController = "";
    string currentAction = "";

    HttpContext httpContext = ((MvcApplication)sender).Context;
    HttpRequestWrapper httpRequest = new HttpRequestWrapper(httpContext.Request);


    RouteData currentRouteData = RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData(new HttpContextWrapper(httpContext));
    if (!(currentRouteData == null))
    {
        if (currentRouteData.Values["controller"] != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(currentRouteData.Values["controller"].ToString()))
        {
            currentController = currentRouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
        }
        if (currentRouteData.Values["action"] != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(currentRouteData.Values["action"].ToString()))
        {
            currentAction = currentRouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
        }
    }


    var exception = Server.GetLastError();
    if (exception == null)
        return;

    // Clear the error
    Server.ClearError();

    Models.Exception ex = new Models.Exception();
    ex.ErrorMessage = exception.Message;
    ex.ErrorUrl = String.Format("{0}/{1}", currentController, currentAction);

    FreelancerDB.SaveExceptions(ex);

    Response.Redirect("~/WebsiteAccess/SystemError");
}
```

The problem is that I dont understand what is happening in these 2 linies:

```
HttpContext httpContext = ((MvcApplication)sender).Context;
HttpRequestWrapper httpRequest = new HttpRequestWrapper(httpContext.Request);
```

Can anyone explain what is happening here?

Comment: Have you tried to go to the MSN site and check what the classes do? A simple search on google for the httpRequestWrapper bring https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequestwrapper(v=vs.110).aspx, and a description of what the class does, other search links point to how to use it.

Comment: "Encapsulates the HTTP intrinsic object that enables ASP.NET to read the HTTP values that are sent by a client during a Web request."

****
It makes no sense in my head. What do they mean by that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing is happening there, the `httpRequest` variable isn't used afterwards.

It does give you a reference to the request during which the exception was generated, might you need it.

Comment: They are used here: 
 RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData(new HttpContextWrapper(httpContext));
???

Comment: Yes, that's the `httpContext` variable, not the `httpRequest` variable. What part of that code don't you understand, and what are you trying to get to know? To obtain the route data for the current request, you need its context, which is exactly what's happening there.

Comment: What exactly is httpcontext,.I have difficulty understanding this. what is the purpose ! ?

But why we looking for the Current request her... and not the Prev request ... It was the Prev request which threw expention...wasnt it ?

Comment: The purpose of the HttpContext object obtained in that method is to give you information about the current HTTP request. There has to be _some_ way to provide this information, and the ASP.NET team chose to introduce this class. You just have to deal with it. And no, Application_Error is fired while you're still in the pipeline of handling the _current_ request.

Comment: And again, it would really help if you could explain **why** you're asking this question. The question you asked is answered, but you seem to have additional questions, so you might not have asked the question you actually want answered.